# Apache2 server shows different interface with django server , at the same site

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

These days, i set up apache2 and mod_wsgi to hold my django site, but when i test with a hello world django site, the apache2 shows defferent interface with the server django come up with ,ie,`manage.py runserver`

the django server shows [here](http://postimg.org/image/3v5ib9wo3/)

and the apache shows [there](http://postimg.org/image/73el228bn/)

so, I don't  whether I did something wrong with apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is likely simple , you have to link django admin static files to the production files use by your apache2.

```
 let say that your web production files are in /var/www/www.localhost.com/


 in the settings.py files add the path ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/localhost/admin_media/'

 now you have to link the static file to django default admin static files :
 by using [apps_path_to_admin_static]$ sudo ln -s [path to django]/static/admin
 example :
 ali@host:/var/www/www.localhost.com/localhost/static$ sudo ln - s 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin

in apache2 virtualhost add the path:

Alias /admin_media /var/www/www.localhost.com/localhost/static/admin_media
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not told Apache correctly where your static media assets are. See the Alias directives described in:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files